# How can I control the MS Graph event order sequence?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail, microsoft-graph-calendar

I've implemented an app that subscribes to MS Graph events. One problem that I have is that sometimes I get Updated events before the corresponding Created events. I've also seen events for mail messages where the response to a message comes before the actual message. This makes is pretty hard to process all events robustly.

Is there a way to control the order of events in MS Graph Subscriptions? How do I ensure that events that depend/reference other events arrive in order?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your best solution is likely to not solely rely on the Notifications that you are getting from the webhook but to combine this with the Delta Query functionality.

There's a tutorial on this approach: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/change-notifications